# Drop columns from Pandas dataframe if they are not in specific list

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and it has some columns. I want to drop columns if they are not presented at a list.

pandas dataframe columns:

```
list(pandas_df.columns.values)
```

Result:

```
['id', 'name' ,'region', 'city']
```

And my expected column names:

```
final_table_columns = ['id', 'name', 'year']
```

After x operations result should be:

```
list(pandas_df.columns.values)

['id', 'name']
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) to find the intersection of an index and a list of (column) labels:

```
pandas_df = pandas_df[pandas_df.columns.intersection(final_table_columns)]
```

Comment: Hi @unutbu, how would you go about doing the same thing bu with case insensitive string matching ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Use `Index.intersection()`, if the number of columns to **keep** is small, compared to those to exclude. In the opposite case (**exclude** only a few of a large number) `Index.difference()` may be the better choice. White-listing vs. black-listing.

Answer (score 29):

You could use a list comprehension creating all column-names to `drop()`

```
final_table_columns = ['id', 'name', 'year']
df = df.drop(columns=[col for col in df if col not in final_table_columns])
```

To do it in-place:

```
df.drop(columns=[col for col in df if col not in final_table_columns], inplace=True)
```

Comment: why not simply `df = df[final_table_columns]`

Answer (score 14):

To do it in-place, consider [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html). This was not documented in any prior answer.

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns.difference(final_table_columns), inplace=True)
```

To create a new dataframe, [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) also works.

```
df_final = df.drop(columns=df.columns.difference(final_table_columns)

df_final = df[df.columns.intersection(final_table_columns)]  # credited to unutbu
```

Comment: Can you make this a soft drop, as in, if it contains one of the words in the column then you should keep the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this much more simply

```
df = df[final_table_columns]
```

Comment: This will give a key error, because `year` is not in the DF's columns.

Comment: Yes I see you’re correct now - but the question remains.  Why then would he include that in his final columns? He can simply change the list to remove it.  Much simpler.