# Pythonic way of dropping columns used in assign (i.e. Pandas equivalent of `.keep = "unused"`)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In dplyr package of R, there's the option `.keep = "unused"` when creating new columns with the function `mutate()` (which is their equivalent of `assign`).

An example, for those who haven't used it:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# any column used in creating `new_col` is dropped afterwards automatically
> mutate(.data = head(iris), new_col = Sepal.Length + Petal.Length * Petal.Width, .keep = "unused")
  Sepal.Width Species new_col
1         3.5  setosa    5.38
2         3.0  setosa    5.18
3         3.2  setosa    4.96
4         3.1  setosa    4.90
5         3.6  setosa    5.28
6         3.9  setosa    6.08
```

I *say* they are equivalent, but there doesn't appear to be the option for doing this with `assign` in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) so I assume it doesn't exist. I was curious about creating a way of doing something similar then.

One way I can think of to do this is to create a list of names beforehand, and drop them afterwards, like this:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd

used_columns = ['sepal length (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']

iris = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_iris().data, columns=datasets.load_iris().feature_names)

iris.assign(new_col = lambda x: x['sepal length (cm)'] + x['petal length (cm)'] * x['petal width (cm)']).drop(used_columns, axis=1)
```

or

```
iris.assign(new_col = lambda x: x[used_columns[0]] + x[used_columns[1]] * x[used_columns[2]]).drop(used_columns, axis=1)
```

Which seems  ~*fine*~, but requires a separate list, and with the first one, keeping two things updated, and with the second, the cognitive load of keeping track of what the nth list item is in my head.

So I was curious if there's another way I'm not aware of of doing this, that would be easier to maintain? Both of the ones above seem not very Pythonic?

Research I've done: I did a bunch of googling around this, with no luck. It seems [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140011/pandasdrop-multiple-columns-which-name-in-a-list-and-assigned-to-a-new-datafram) [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167612/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-columns-in-pandas) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389018/dropping-multiple-columns-from-a-dataframe) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe/18145399#18145399) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071199/drop-columns-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string-from-pandas-dataframe) [dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891518/drop-columns-from-pandas-dataframe-if-they-are-not-in-specific-list) [columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347412/drop-multiple-columns-in-pandas), but none I've found seem particularly well-suited to this type of situation. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated! Answers which use other Python packages (e.g. `janitor`) are okay too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never used `R` but based on the definition of `unused` and AFIK, to simulate the same behaviour in pandas, you will need to [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) each column from a [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) of the original DataFrame :

> `"unused"` *retains only the columns not used in ... to create new columns. This is useful if you generate new columns, but no longer need the columns used to generate them.*
>
> `DataFrame.pop(item)` *returns item and drops from frame. Raises KeyError if not found.*

---

```
(
    iris.copy().assign(
        new_col= lambda x: x.pop('sepal length (cm)')
        + x.pop('petal length (cm)') * x.pop('petal width (cm)'))
)
```

Output :

```
     sepal width (cm)  new_col
0                 3.5     5.38
1                 3.0     5.18
2                 3.2     4.96
3                 3.1     4.90
4                 3.6     5.28
..                ...      ...
145               3.0    18.66
146               2.5    15.80
147               3.0    16.90
148               3.4    18.62
149               3.0    15.08

[150 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: **NB**: If you need to drop the columns from the original *DataFrame*, remove `copy()`.

Comment: I didn't realise you could `pop` columns! Thank you for sharing this :-)

Comment: @Timeless Very good answer

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Timeless's answer:

```py
iris["new_col"] = iris.pop("sepal length (cm)") + iris.pop("petal length (cm)") * iris.pop("petal width (cm)")
print(iris.head())
```

Prints:

```
   sepal width (cm)  new_col
0               3.5     5.38
1               3.0     5.18
2               3.2     4.96
3               3.1     4.90
4               3.6     5.28
```

Comment: I should have clarified, that despite it's name, `mutate()` isn't actually a mutating function - it doesn't change the dataframe saved as `iris` unless you choose to redefine iris to the new changed dataframe. This is unlike `.pop()` which does change the input, as I'm sure you already know. Not hugely important in the context of the example df, not is it even objectively worse! - just different :-)

Comment: Can you adding some details

Comment: @XM01-standswithPalestine are you talking to me or to Andrej?